# How to make Xcode debugger tab active on start then switch back original tab on complete?

Tags: xcode, debugging, view, window, behavior

When I run my app I have it where it switches to the debugger tab on start, but when it completes I want to have it switch back to the editor tab I was originally at.

In the behavior settings under Running>Starts I have "Show tab named debugger in active window"
This works perfect but I can't get it to switch back when it's complete.
For the Completes setting I tried replacing the show tab name with the name it shows on the tab but it is not switching to back to it.

My main objective is to have it where when I run my program it makes a fullscreen debugger window active, then when I exit I want to switch back to the fullscreen editor I was at.

Any help would be awesome! Thanks!